# Trying to get property 'designation_name' of non-object in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to show the user role from my user role table, but I can't.

**User.php**

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Designation');
}
```

**UserController**

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();

    return view('dashboard2', compact('user'));
}
```

**View**

```
<h1>{{ Auth::user()->role->designation_name}}</h1>
```

Comment: are you sure this is work? `'App\Models\Designation'` replace via `Designation::class`

Comment: @Milad I also try Designation::class But its not working please help me

Comment: A lot of things are wrong here, first you return $user in view but you get user with Auth::user() if user not authenticated you got trouble. next, this user you called exist? and have any role? for more check `$user = User::find(1); return $user->role->designation_name` / if every think is okay edit your post and put your tables. role and user table

Comment: `Designation::class` should return `'App\Models\Designation'`; they're syntactically equivalent. Your main issue (amongst the ones noted above) is that `auth()->user()->role` is `null`, so you can't access `designation_name`. `{{ auth()->user()->role ? auth()->user()->role->designation_name : 'No Designation Name...' }}` (or other methods for checking existence _before_ trying to access) will solve this, but you have lots of other issues too.

Answer (score 1):

You actually should have shared more details about the relationships. But I will give an answer based on an assumption. It seems like there is a one-to-one relationship betwen User and Role as well as Role and Designation. So you want to reach designation from user. Based on that:

```
//User.php

public function role()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

```
//Role.php

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}


public function designation()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Designation::class);
}
```

```
//Designation.php

public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

```
// Controller
public function index()
{
    // If you need only the auth user's data, you don't
    // need adding relationships into the query. 
    $users = User::with('role.desgination')->all();

    return view('dashboard2', compact('users'));
}
```

```
// View

// For auth user: 
// I haven't used this way before,
// but technically it should work.
auth()->role()->designation()->name;

// For users collection:
// Make sure you added the query to the controller.
@foreach($users as $user)
    $user->role->desgination->name
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did you add the namespace properly?